# Tuning paramters on xgbTree not working anymore?

Tags: r, r-caret

For a few days now, the tuning parameter has stopped working when I try to train a model with caret and xgbTree. Before that, everything always has worked fine. Here is the error I am receiving:

```
[16:45:38] WARNING: amalgamation/../src/learner.cc:516: 
Parameters: { tune } might not be used.

  This may not be accurate due to some parameters are only used in language bindings but
  passed down to XGBoost core.  Or some parameters are not used but slip through this
  verification. Please open an issue if you find above cases.
```

My model looks like this:

```
set.seed(79647)
xgb <- train(dv ~ .,
             data = model_train,
             method = "xgbTree",
             trControl = ctrl,
             tune = expand.grid(max_depth = 3,
                    nrounds = 50,
                    eta = 0.4,
                    min_child_weight = 1,
                    subsample = 0.8,
                    gamma = 0,
                    colsample_bytree = 0.8,
                    subsample = 1),
             metric = "ROC")
```

I can't work out what is causing this error and a google search with the error message did not guide me to anything. Does anybody has some possible insights on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified `subsample` twice in your call, and also the tuning parameters should be feed into the function using `tuneGrid =` , not `tune=`

If you try something below, it should work, I don't have your trainControl so I use the basic below:

```
Grid = expand.grid(nrounds = 50,
                  max_depth = 2:3,
                  eta = 0.4,
                    min_child_weight = 1,
                    subsample = 0.8,
                    gamma = 0,
                    colsample_bytree = 0.8)

xgb <- train(Species ~ .,
             data = iris,
             method = "xgbTree",
             trControl = trainControl(method="cv"),
             tuneGrid =Grid)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out these silly mistakes. Of course it works now...